# prolog printing lists

Tags: ascii, prolog

```
?-mod5(X,[a,16,b,c(5),[[12]],8]).  
X = [a,1,b,c(5),[[12]],3].
```

A non-integer should remain untouched. However, in the case of [[12]], since 12 is the ASCII value of "\f" (form feed), it outputs [["\f"]] when what I want it to output [[12]] as is. How can I prevent this?

Comment: @Kaarel: ["The homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @sher, please follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** At first, I assumed the problem was with the implementation, which is why I've suggested one below. It turns out, given the OP has later informed that this is NU-Prolog, that the answer seems to lie simply in the default behaviour of [NU-Prolog](http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/~lee/src/nuprolog/), as [per this manual, section 3.7](http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/~lee/src/nuprolog/text.ps.gz):

> "Lists are usually printed as strings if every element of the list is an integer for which `isPrint/1` is true."

As `isPrint/1` is denoted to be a built-in for NU-Prolog, it is possible it may not be overridden to provide other behaviour - perhaps NU-Prolog can be configured to alter the default behaviour in this case, but I'm uncertain.

Below is an implementation of `mod5/2`, which is now irrelevant to the solution:

---

If the predicate `mod5/2` is intended to take (as a second argument) a list of terms, and return (in the first argument position) a list of terms in the same order, but where every number N is replaced with the value of N mod 5, then I suggest you try:

```
mod5([], []).
mod5([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
    isInt(Y), !,
    X is Y mod 5,
    mod5(Xs, Ys).
mod5([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
    mod5(Xs, Ys).
```

Note the guard subgoals `isInt(Y), !,` (NU-PROLOG) in the second clause of `mod5/2`; the numeric calculation of `mod` via `is` to replace `Y` will only occur iff `Y` is numeric; otherwise, it is passed through untouched by the last clause of `mod5` (as `X`).

Executing this with your example using SWI-PROLOG gives:

```
?- mod5(X,[a,16,b,c(5),[[12]],8]).  
X = [a, 1, b, c(5), [[12]], 3] ;
false.
```

Comment: I'm doing something similar to this. If the element is a number it is modified else I leave it untouched. I'm using NU prolog, your solution did not work. the output is the same as the input except ["\f"]. 
X = [a, 16, b, c(5), ["\f"], 8] ;

Comment: mod is not defined on all numbers: you want to replace number/1 with integer/1

Comment: @sher: I have updated my answer. The behaviour you've described seems to be the default behaviour of NU-Prolog (at least, in two NU-Prolog manuals I have seen).